# Routing for nested categories, generate url path

Tags: routes, typo3, extbase

I have nested categories like "category a" has a child "category b".
I would like to have an url who respects this like `/category-a/category-b`.

Well, I can combine fields or write my own slug or use a hook to generate the complete slug with parent categories. Somehow that works.

But I always get a problem in the frontend from symphony:

> `Parameter "tx_apgallery_category__category" for route
>   "tx_apgallery_category_0" must match "[^/]++" ("/category-a-2-3"
>   given) to generate a corresponding URL.`

Seems like a slash in an url is not allowed. What choice do I have to allow the slash or is there another idea behind how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You should post one of your YAML site configuration. That would help others to suggest a solution for your configuration.

Comment: The YAML looks very simple and works fine for one category:

routeEnhancers:
  ApGalleryCategory:
    type: Extbase
    extension: ApGallery
    plugin: Category
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/{category_slug}', _controller: 'Category::show', _arguments: {'category_slug': 'category'} }
    defaultController: 'Category::show'
    aspects:
      category_slug:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'sys_category'
        routeFieldName: 'tx_apgallery_slug'